# How to give the user a choice of closing a wpf window from its window_loaded event

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I do some checking when a WPF window opens by some code in the Window_loaded sub of the WPF Window.

In certain conditions, I need to give the a choice to a user via a messagebox.show and close the window.

```
        If MessageBox.Show("Question the user?",
                         "Ask", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question) = MessageBoxResult.OK Then
          'do some further code
        Else
          Me.Close()
        End If
```

Currently when I do this, when the Messagebox shows up, the wpf window is shown as a black window.

**Question1: How can I get the messageBox without showing the WPF window as a black box behind it**

Here's the full code in the load_window event.

```
'Initialise window when Load event flagged
'The window expects to called after a Status variable is set to the newly   created window object
'status=1 then it attempts to load the current activity
'status=2 then it checks the user has a current activity, offers to a)stop and save it and then open a new activity Or b) close.
'status=other, shouldn't happen, theres an error close the application

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
log.logInDB(clsLoggedInUser.login, "CurrentActivityWindow", "Info", "Form Loading. Status" & status)

Select Case Me.status
  Case 1 'Current Activity
    'Ask the Activity to load details for the users current Activity
    Debug.Print("Window loaded - current Activity")
    myActivity.GetCurrentActivityForUser(clsLoggedInUser.login)
  Case 2 'New Activity
    Debug.Print("Window loaded - new Activity")
    myActivity.GetCurrentActivityForUser(clsLoggedInUser.login)
    If myActivity.ID > 0 Then
      log.logInDB(clsLoggedInUser.login, "CurrentActivityWindow", "Info", "User already has an activity. Stop it and save or close")
      If myActivity.activityStart.HasValue Then
        If MessageBox.Show("Already have an active activity, Stop it and create a new one?",
                         "New Activity", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question) = MessageBoxResult.OK Then
          'stop and create new one
          myActivity.StopActivity()
          myActivity.save()
          log.logInDB(clsLoggedInUser.login, "CurrentActivityWindow", "Info", "Setting up New Activity")
          newActivity()
        Else
          Debug.Print("Closing Form - Opened as new activity but user has a current activity and didnt want to stop it.")
          Me.Close()
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Else
        If MessageBox.Show("Already have an active activity without a start time, will load that up for you.",
             "New Activity", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information) = MessageBoxResult.OK Then
        End If
      End If
    Else
      log.logInDB(clsLoggedInUser.login, "CurrentActivityWindow", "Info", "No current Activity, calling newActivity")
      newActivity()
    End If
  Case Else
    Debug.Print("Error: CurrentActivity Status not set")
    log.logInDB(clsLoggedInUser.login, "CurrentActivityWindow", "Info", "Tried opening window without Status being set.")
    Application.Current.Shutdown()
End Select

Debug.Print("CurrentActivityWindow - Filling Project List")
buildProjectList()
DataContext = projectsList

Debug.Print("CurrentActivityWindow - Updating GUI")
updateGUI()
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the popup WPF window to be loaded before you ask your question?

Answer to your `Question1`:
You can call `MessageBox.Show()` in the constructor of the popup WPF window.

I would do something like this:

**Step #1:** Let's assume there is a `PopupWindow` for your case.

```
Public Class PopupWindow

    ' We use this custom property to decide whether we need to show this window or not.
    Public Property CanOpen As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        CanOpen = True
        ' To not display the WPF window you can ask your question from the constructor
        If MessageBox.Show(
            "Question?", "Ask", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question
        ) = MessageBoxResult.Cancel Then
            CanOpen = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Step #2:** In caller window e.g. in a button click event handler we decide to open the `PopupWindow` or not.

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim popupWindow As PopupWindow = New PopupWindow()

    ' At this point our custom property already contains the value
    ' based on the answer provided by the user to our question
    ' because the question is asked within the constructor
    ' we called in the previous statement.
    If (Not popupWindow.CanOpen) Then
        ' Do what you would do in PopupWindow.Closed event
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Until this point the window is not shown.
    popupWindow.Owner = Me
    popupWindow.ShowDialog()

    MessageBox.Show("Popup closed.", "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)
End Sub
```

**Please note:** It is a better solution to ask your question in the caller window's button click event handler before creating a new instance of the `PopupWindow`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Gabor.  The question I ask depends on the initialisation code in the window.  Basically the initialisation grabs data from a DB and on a particular circumstance, it needs to ask the user whether to continue or not.  The inisiliasation code is better left in the new window rather than the calling window as otherwise I'll have unrelated code in the calling window and it'll end up a sprawling mess. :-).  Am I better off putting all the initialisation code in the new constructor?

Comment: You shouldn't access DB from any constructor! They cannot contain heavy tasks. Consider creating a `NavigationService` class with `OpenSomeWindow()` method that can call `GetDataForSomeWindow()` method in `YourRepository` class and based on the circumstances `OpenSomeWindow()` method can ask the user and depending on the answer can create a new instance of `NewWindow` and then show it. The caller window can have an instance of `NavigationService` and call its `OpenSomeWindow()` method. Of course these names are just examples. Let me know if you need a concrete example implementation of my idea

Comment: Yep. I don't normally put DB code in a constructor but I'm new to WPF. :-)  I've listed my code in the hope it may make why I ask at this point clearer.  I want to encapsulate the logic in this window rather than the calling window as the calling window is just basically a menu.  Are you saying it's Impossible to get a message box up unless I code it outside the Codebehind of the actual window?

Comment: Based on your code I would say that you can use my solution (move the initializing code to the constructor) except the last step. The `updateGUI()` can remain in the `Window_Loaded()` event handler. Because it will be executed only if the window should be displayed.